# win32 console application on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, console-application, windows-10

I've just installed visual studio 2015 community version and coded a "hello world" win32 console application.

When I hit the Ctrl + F5 (Run without debugging), a cmd window pops up and nothing happens. The cmd window freezes and I can't type anything (even Ctrl+d or Ctrl+c to quit from the program.)

So I moved the same .exe file to another computer running windows 7 and it worked just fine.

Comment: You need to post your code as your description is insufficient to provide you any help. Windows 10 supports running Win32 console applications. VS 2015 community supports coding them. Also, what happens if you run with debugging on Windows 10?

Comment: If I start debugging, the whole Visual Studio 2015 program freezes. It's just a simple hello world program with only one printf function.

Comment: I solved it. I stopped real time protection of AVAST free anti virus software. I think it stops me from starting unknown exe file.